# Fire an event when user reselects select box value

Tags: jquery, select, alert

I got a simple select drop down box with 2 options in Jquery.

I can successfully get the values of it when i change between the options.

```
<select name="Point" id="Point" style="width:10em; display: inline; font-size:14px; width:150px; font-family: 'Source Code Pro', sans-serif; color:#333; font-weight:bold;"  >
<option id="Accomodation"  value="1">One</option>
<option id="Point on map" value="2">Two</option>
```

The problem is that i cannot get an event triggered when i choose the option that is already show in the select box. For example in the below jsfiddle i have a select box with options "one" and "two" if "one" is shown and i select "two" the alert fires but if "one" is show and i open the drop down box and click on "one" again nothing happens....can i somehow fire an event if the user reselects the already shown options?

**[FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/zarcrash/kkeCg/)**

Comment: No you can't, the change event only fires when the value actually changes. Next best thing would be one of the other mouse events, like click, but it won't be the same.

Comment: change event wont fire. you need to try hover or click event to handle it

Answer (score 0):

You can use other event like:

```
$("#Point").mouseup(function() {...
```

But it is not very elegant in user experience.